# Can I use the adjective “existing” with a noun, if there are no existing instances of that noun?

Tags: british-english, speech

Would the following sentence make sense, if there are no existing instances the noun?

> I will go out and look for existing dinosaurs

By using the adjective “existing”, the sentence refers to something non-existing, which is contradictory, in reality?

Sorry, if the question is odd, but it has made my head spinning.

Comment: Why would you want to say that, if we know there are no living dinosaurs? If it's something you _don't_ know about, you might say "I would like to know if there any copies of [a particular very old book] _in existence_".

Comment: Thank you, Kate. I know the sentence is convoluted. But what about “I’m looking for an existing car, that costs less than 100$”, or “I’m looking for an existing girl that likes me”?

Comment: These sentences are not unreasonable, yet there may be no of the objects in existence

Comment: Those sentences are unnatural, because nobody would look for a _non-existent_ car or girl, so there is no need to specify 'existing'. You would be looking to find out _whether_ one like that exists.

Comment: Not to throw a wrench, but there are plenty of existing dinosaurs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bird.

Comment: It is puzzling why this was tagged 'british-english'. Is there any reason to think that different versions of the language differ in this respect?

Comment: Maybe "extant" would be a better word, maybe referring to dinosaur-like creatures that may still exist.

Comment: It's grammatical. It just isn't demonstrably true. So you can use it in any construction. Grammar is not about truth or existence; it's about words, and that's all. Lie all you want.

Answer (score 5):

> I will go out and look for existing dinosaurs.
> I’m looking for an existing car that costs less than $100.
> I’m looking for an existing girl who likes me.

*Existing* just isn't used like that. If you're looking for something, you are assuming that it exists, or you wouldn't be looking for it. All of those sentences simply don't use *existing:*

> I will go out and look for dinosaurs.
> I’m looking for a car that costs less than $100.
> I’m looking for a girl who likes me.

The uncertainty of whether something does actually exist is introduced by the determiner **any:**

> You use *any* in positive statements when you are referring to someone or something of a particular kind that might exist, occur, or be involved in a situation, when their exact identity or nature is not important.
>
> — [Collins: any](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/any) sense 3

> I will go out and look for any dinosaurs.
> I’m looking for any car that costs less than $100.
> I’m looking for any girl who likes me.

All of those sentences indicate that you're not sure whether such a thing exists, but the first one you find will satisfy you.

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/existing) is useful in explaining *existing* (my emphases):

> *Existing* is used to describe something which is **now** present, available, or in operation, **especially when you are contrasting it** with something which is planned for the future. [And it also works for the past.]

> The existing stock of $100 cars is a lot smaller than it was a year ago.

The answer to the question "Can I use the adjective *existing* with a noun, if there are no existing instances of that noun?" is **No.**

Comment: Thank you, @AndrewLeach. It clarifies things a lot. I should rephrase my sentences with *any* for correctness. Now, for a follow up question: if someone says **I'm looking for a girl that likes me**, what do they actually mean, if they are not sure whether such girl exist, i.e. girls exist, but one that actually likes the person might not? In that case, what they actually mean is **I'm looking for *any* girl that likes me**?

Comment: Yes, broadly (but not exactly). In my example sentences you could replace *any* with *a* and they would mean roughly the same thing. There's a lot more nuance and you could ask a separate question.

Comment: Also, would it be right to consider a noun to refer to an instance of that noun that might exist? In that case, **I'm looking for a girl that likes me** makes sense, but **I'm looking for an existing girl that likes me** still doesn't make sense, since the adjective asserts the girl exists

Comment: Can *a* mean the same thing as *any*? If so, then all sentences of the form **I'm looking for a <NOUN> that likes me** actually make sense! Thanks :)

Comment: Re your second comment: that's exactly what my answer shows.

Comment: Thank you. What about the first comment? In general, a noun can refer to an imaginary, incomplete, unrealized, etc. instance of that noun?

Comment: Only your comment strikes the semantic equality between *a* and *any*, the answer is still missing it

Comment: It's quite possible to pair 'any' with 'existing': 'The amount of scientific investigation over the past eighty years would surely have brought to light any existing dinosaurs' (though '... still in existence' would doubtless be more usual). Such sentences negate/query the existence of the referent.

Comment: I didn't say anything about *any/a* because it's far more nuanced than an answer for a question about *existing.* Same for @EdwinAshworth: if you are dissatisfied with an answer **write your own.** I think I've said that before and I shall start flagging these carping comments.

Comment: They are not all critical. This one is an addition to your answer; it does not criticise at all. But your answer has the meat of the response, rendering another answer superfluous.  ELU is about comprehensive and accurate analysis.

Comment: @Shuzheng no one else is saying it, so I will. You should accept Andrew Leech's answer by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

> I will go out and look for existing dinosaurs.

"existing dinosaurs" can be understood as **the type** of dinosaur that still is in existence (despite the usual type all being extinct.)

As birds are the descendants of dinosaurs, it is possible to refer to birds as "existing dinosaurs".

If "dinosaur" is used in the extended sense of *"someone whose attitudes are firmly set in the past, or noticeably old-fashioned - particular attitudes on social issues"* then "existing dinosaurs" also works.

If, despite being informed that dinosaurs are extinct, a person has it in their mind that real dinosaurs still exist (e.g. somewhere deep inside South America; as per Conan Doyle's "Lost World"), then "I will go out and look for existing dinosaurs" is valid.

> I’m looking for an existing car that costs less than $100.

This could be used in a certain context:

A: I want a cheap car.

B: My father had a Jaguar that he sold to a scrapyard for $120.

A: That's not much use! I’m looking for an ***existing*** car that costs less than $100. (A car that is currently in existence.)

Likewise "an existing girl" can be in emphatic contrast to a fictional character or someone who is dead.

Answer (score 0):

The only contexts I can think of where you would use **existing** in that manner, as an attributive adjective describing an entity known or thought to be non-existent, rather than a relative clause like "that really do exist", is in situations where the question whether such and such an entity may actually exist has been the topic of conversation or discussion, and the adjective is being used advisedly for particular emphasis.

> People take an immediate dislike to me.
>
> -- People like and admire you. Don't feel so down about yourself!
>
> Like who? Name one existing person who likes and admires me!

There "existing person" means far more than "person alive". It is a word meant to be taken as an expression of great skepticism about the other person's remark. It means "a person who is not a figment of your imagination or a person you're not pretending really exists, just to make me feel better."

You could be conversing with some cryptozoologists who are in your office at National Geographic headquarters, where you are the CEO, and they are getting more and more upset because you're not taking them seriously and offering to fund their research. And so you say to them (while surreptitiously texting Security for help) :

> "OK, OK. National Geographic will fund your expedition to the deepest reaches of the Amazon so you can look for existing dinosaurs."

It is a "meta-linguistic" usage. You are using the word *existing* advisedly, and with an intonation that gives it a particular emphasis. In the conversation about being liked and admired, it has an ironic and skeptical tone, and means "not imaginary" or "not merely something you believe" or "not merely something you're saying to make me feel better" and in the conversation with the cryptozoologists it has a placating tone (masking the underlying skepticism).

With such metalinguistic uses, this particular category of metalinguistic use, which is a distant cousin of the *irrealis*, the speaker does not have 100% belief in the word. It is being used with "scare-quotes" or with a special meaning that it usually does not have, as in @Greybeard's answer, where "existing" is being given the meaning "descendant of a now-extinct species and thus, in a way, a member of that species".

P.S.
We can compare these usages to so-called metalinguistic comparisons like "he is more clever than rude", which draw attention to the meaning of the words rather than merely using them in their lexical sense. The speaker is implicitly asking the interlocutor to consider that the former word,"clever", might be more apt than the latter, "rude".  In these examples with **existing**, something similar is going on. The speaker is drawing attention to the special signficance of the word in context. In the first, "Name one *existing* person..." the word 'existing' means something like  "'existing', that is, 'real' -- *as distinct from 'imaginary' as I can see that you're just trying to make me feel better*",and in the second example with National Geographic, the word 'existing' is used advisedly to placate the interlocutor. The tone placed upon the word says to the interlocutor, I hope you understand the significance of me choosing this word.

Comment: I would appreciate the reason for the downvote.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you characterise this use of the word as **meta**linguistic? If, as you say, it is an 'expression of great skepticism', it seems to be confronting one's interlocutor directly (at the same level at which that person has spoken), rather than being a metalevel comment about the words one's interlocutor has used.

Comment: @jsw29: It was too long for a comment so I've added a P.S.

Answer (score 0):

There is certainly nothing **grammatically** wrong with saying 'I will go out and look for existing dinosaurs'. The grammar of English language does not preclude attaching *existing* to *dinosaurs*, nor does it imply anything about whether dinosaurs exist; our knowledge that they don't exist any more comes from the sources outside our command of the language itself. Nor is the sentence self-contradictory: nothing **within the sentence** implies that dinosaurs do not exist. Our knowledge that they do not comes from something outside that sentence. There would be something self-contradictory about saying 'I will go out and look for existing dinosaurs, which do not exist', but that is not the sentence we are analysing.

The word *existing* is akin to [*real*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/482316/is-really-redundant-redundant/482389#482389), in that it is normally redundant. When one speaks of an X, one normally speaks of it **as** existing, so there is normally no need to explicitly characterise it as an existing X. It would thus, outside the special contexts discussed below, be very strange to hear somebody say 'I will go out and look for existing Xs', regardless of what Xs are. This is so even if Xs are, in fact, something fictional or hypothetical: when one speaks of unicorns, one speaks of them as existing within a particular fairy-tale universe. A fairy tale wouldn't say that its hero will go out and look for existing unicorns; that would be redundant. Anybody who would go out to look for dinosaurs must conceive of them as possibly existing, and must think that, if they are found, the ones that are found will be the existing ones. So, again, it would be redundant for such a person to say that the objects of the search are existing dinosaurs. Note that it would be **redundant**, not self-contradictory.

Now, even though *existing* is always redundant as a matter of semantics, it may sometimes have a role to play, so far as pragmatics is concerned. Whenever the setting is such that one's audience is likely to have doubts as to whether X exists, saying that it is an existing X has a purpose: it conveys that the speaker has considered these doubts and in spite of them thinks of X as possibly existing. We can thus imagine a situation in which somebody has, in spite of the practically universal belief that dinosaurs are extinct, developed a theory that some dinosaurs somehow still exist somewhere, and therefore now wants to go out and look for these 'existing dinosaurs'. The use of the word *existing* by such a person in this context would still be semantically redundant (one wouldn't look for the dinosaurs if one didn't envisage finding them existing), but it would serve a pragmatic purpose of making it explicit that one is aware that one's assumptions are different from those of the person one is talking to. It effectively tells the interlocutor: 'yes, I know that you think that there are no dinosaurs to be found anywhere, but I disagree, and that's why I am going to look for them'. If something like that is the context for the sentence that the question is about, then there is nothing wrong with it. It is, however, a highly unusual context; only the OP knows whether this was intended by the sentence.